# Fixing a Run-On Equation

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox, ifxetex, ifluatex}
\ifboolexpr{bool{xetex} or bool{luatex}}{
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant = american, ordinalmonthday = true]{english}
}{
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \begin{aligned} 
            &\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{X} \ldotp \left(a \leq b \land b \leq a \Rightarrow a = b\right) \land \left(a \leq b \land b \leq c \Rightarrow a \leq c \right) \land \left( a \leq b \lor b \leq a \right) \\
            &\left( \forall A \right) \left( \left( \left( \exists w \right) \left( w \in A \right) \land \left(\exists z \right)\left( \forall u \right)\left(u \in A \Rightarrow u \leq z \right) \right) \Rightarrow \left( \exists x \right)\left( \forall y \right)\left( \left( \forall w \right)\left(w \in A \Rightarrow w \leq y \right) \Leftrightarrow \left(x \leq y \right) \right) \right) \\
            &\vdots \\
            &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \; \ldotp \forall \mathcal{P}\!\left(x\right) \ldotp \left\{\,x : \mathcal{P}\!\left(x\right) \,\right\} \ldotp \dots
        \end{aligned}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

The second logical formula, a statement of the least-upper-bound property, goes off of the right side of the PDF that results from processing this code using LuaLaTeX in TeXShop for OS X under OS X 10.10.3 'Yosemite.'  How do I fix this?

Comment: Find a break point (say, after—or before, if you swing that way—`\land` or `\Rightarrow`) and continue it on the next line (probably with a `\quad` or `\qquad` to make it clear that it's a continuation and not a new formula)?

Comment: @LSpice:  Tried doing something similar with some other alignment environments, but all attempts at this failed due to unpaired `\left(`/`\right)` pairs.

Comment: You need *no* `\left` and `\right` in those formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `multlined`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{multlined}[.9\displaywidth]
  \forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{X} \ldotp (a \leq b \land b \leq a \Rightarrow a = b) \\
    \land (a \leq b \land b \leq c \Rightarrow a \leq c) \land (a \leq b \lor b \leq a)
\end{multlined}\\
&\begin{multlined}[.9\displaywidth]
 (\forall A)(((\exists)(w\in A)\land (\exists z)(\forall u)(u \in A \Rightarrow u \leq z))
 \\
 \Rightarrow ( \exists x )( \forall y )( ( \forall w )(w \in A \Rightarrow w \leq y )
 \Leftrightarrow (x \leq y ) ) )
\end{multlined}\\
&\vdots \\
&\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ldotp \forall \mathcal{P}(x) \ldotp
  \{\,x : \mathcal{P}\!(x) \,\} \ldotp \dots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes.

1. Don't use `utf8x`, but `utf8`. I omitted the loading part that's irrelevant for the problem at hand.
2. All the `\left` and `\right` commands you had are completely useless.
3. An “exists” in the second line is missing the variable; I didn't try fixing it.
4. The necessity of `\!` after `\mathcal{P}` is exactly due to a wrong `\left`–`\right` pair.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll implement the advice you gave in your first note, fix the problem you noted in your third note, and keep the other advice you gave in mind.